# git: empty arguments in post-receive hook

Tags: git, bash, githooks

I'm writing post-receive hook basing on the `post-receive-email` script from the `contrib` dir, but it seems that the `oldrev` and `newrev` arguments are empty.

The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

oldrev=$(git rev-parse $1)
newrev=$(git rev-parse $2)
```

The script runs on push, but all `$1`, `$2`, `$oldrev` and `$newrev` are empty. Should I configure something to get it running?

(The repository was created by `gitolite` if it does matter)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `post-receive` hook doesn't take any arguments. Quoth [the manual](http://Kernel.Org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html) (emphasis added):

> This hook is invoked by git-receive-pack on the remote repository, which happens when a git push is done on a local repository. It executes on the remote repository once after all the refs have been updated.
>
> This hook executes once for the receive operation. **It takes no arguments**, but gets the same information as the `pre-receive` hook does on its standard input.
>
> This hook does not affect the outcome of `git-receive-pack`, as it is called after the real work is done.
>
> This supersedes the `post-update` hook in that it gets both old and new values of all the refs in addition to their names.
>
> Both standard output and standard error output are forwarded to `git send-pack` on the other end, so you can simply echo messages for the user.
>
> The default `post-receive` hook is empty, but there is a sample script `post-receive-email` provided in the `contrib/hooks` directory in git distribution, which implements sending commit emails.

Answer (score 54):

I stumbled into this problem while setting up a continuous integration server. Since the arguments are not passed to post-receive via the command line, but are passed over STDIN, you have to use the read command to fetch them. Here is how I did it:

```
#!/bin/sh
read oldrev newrev refname
BRANCH=${refname#refs/heads/} 
curl --request POST "http://my.ci.server/hooks/build/myproject_$BRANCH"
```

Answer (score 13):

There are no arguments though the information is passed over STDIN. To read that information from bash simply do this:

```
read oldrev newrev refname
echo "Old revision: $oldrev"
echo "New revision: $newrev"
echo "Reference name: $refname"
```

I'm just summarizing the answers already posted.

Answer (score 3):

A more elaborated version of François script would be

```
#!/bin/bash

JENKINS_URL="http://192.168.1.116/jenkins"
GIT_URL="git@bitbucket.org:nuclos/nuclos.git"

# remove all spaces and newlines from ARG
trim() {
  local ARG="$1"
  shift
  echo -e "$ARG" | tr -d "[:space:]\n" 
}

# unique sort ARG items separated by newlines
unique() {
  local ARG="$1"
  shift
  echo -e "$ARG" | sort -u -i
}

# cut first and last character from ARG
cutfl() {
  local ARG="$1"
  shift
  local LEN="${#ARG}"
  let LEN="$LEN - 2"
  echo "${ARG:1:$LEN}"
}
BRANCHES=""
while read oldrev newrev refname; do
  BRANCH=`trim ${refname#refs/heads/}`
  if [ -n "$BRANCH" ]; then
    BRANCHES+="${BRANCH}\n"
  fi
done

BRANCHES=`unique "$BRANCHES" | tr '\n' ','`
BRANCHES=`cutfl "$BRANCHES"`
echo wget -q -O - "$JENKINS_URL/git/notifyCommit?url=$GIT_URL&branches=$BRANCHES"
at "now + 5 minutes" <<END
wget -q -O - "$JENKINS_URL/git/notifyCommit?url=$GIT_URL&branches=$BRANCHES"
END
```

This version could cope with more than one branch and only triggers one build for each one.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I don't accept the "it takes no arguments", because the sample script post-receive.sample is having the following comment:

```
# The "post-receive" script is run after receive-pack has accepted a pack
# and the repository has been updated.  It is passed arguments in through
# stdin in the form
#  <oldrev> <newrev> <refname>
# For example:
#  aa453216d1b3e49e7f6f98441fa56946ddcd6a20 68f7abf4e6f922807889f52bc043ecd31b79f814 refs/heads/master
```

Comment: It takes arguments through stdin, this is what is mentioned in the accepted answer

Comment: It is also mentioned in the comment of this script