# git post-receive hook in php

Tags: php, git, githooks

I want to be able to execute a php hook on post-receive hook, to copy files from the git repo to web folder on the same server and only run if it was pushed was made on a master branch ignoring other branches. Below is what I've got so far.

```
!/usr/bin/php
<?php

exec("git archive master | tar -x -C /var/www/", $output);

?>
```

Basically, im not sure how to access git arguments using php.

Comment: +1 because git is awesome and I don't feel like researching the details. hopefully someone else will take care of this quickly and we can all get smarter:)

Comment: a) grab a git library of your choice b) learn some bash

Comment: Ok. Id like to use php if its all the same to you.

Comment: The bit im unsure about is accessig the argument so i can ignore all branches other than the master.

Comment: Look at the parameters passed to the hook in the man page or elsewhere, use $argv[] to access them.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget a post-receive hook **[doesn't take arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3762546/6309)**: it reads data on stdin.

> The "post-receive" script is run after receive-pack has accepted a pack and the repository has been updated.  It is passed arguments in through stdin in the form:

```
<oldrev> <newrev> <refname>
```

So you will need to read said arguments to [extract the branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4807486/6309) (the example is in bash but you can adapt it)

Comment: On reading from stdin from a php script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554760/php-standard-input, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390604/how-to-pass-variables-as-stdin-into-command-line-from-php if `php://stdin` isn't the right stream to read from.