# Post-receive hook does not recognize arguments

Tags: git

I use ssh to access a remote git repository. I add such a simple post-receive script in hooks directory:

```
#/bin/sh
REPO="$1"
REV="$2"
echo $REPO $REV >> /var/log/gitlog
```

I changed the code in local PC and push many times, and I saw nothing in `/var/log/gitlog`. I have checked the permission of post-receive. Its file mask has been set to 777. All users can execute the script on the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That may be because that hook (**`post-receive`**) doesn't take any argument.

See [gitHooks](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-receive):

> This hook is invoked by git-receive-pack on the remote repository, which happens when a git push is done on a local repository. It executes on the remote repository once after all the refs have been updated.
>
> This hook executes once for the receive operation. **It takes no arguments, but gets the same information as the `pre-receive` hook does on its standard input**.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4807486/6309) mentions:

> You have to use the `read` command.

```
#!/bin/sh
read oldrev newrev refname
...
```

Comment: You are correct. I can't use $1 to get the arguments. I copied this script from SVN hooks, and made this problem. Use "read oldrev newrev refname" is the right way. Thanks a lot!