# git trac post-receive hook

Tags: git, trac, git-post-receive

I have upgraded trac from 0.10 to 1.0 recently, and successfully linked the trac instance to svn and git repositories.

However, I got some major problems during set up of git repositories post-receive hook.

I tried the plugin scripts here:

http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/GitPlugin#post-receivehookscripts

but that does not work, as git post receive does not seems provide $OLD_REV and $NEW_REV in the standard input.

The wiki also mentioned that, one only needs to call the following

```
 trac-admin TRAC_ENV changeset added <commitid(s)>
```

So I put the following in the post-receive script of git,

```
REV=$(git rev-parse HEAD)

trac-admin <trac-repo>  changeset added <repo-name> $REV
```

It does work most of the time. However, if the user try to push multiple commits at a time, `git rev-parse HEAD` would only retrieve the last commit ID (instead of a list of commit ID belonging to the last push),  so some commits would be missed from Trac (from the `node_change` table of trac db).

I wonder if there are some ways to get all the commit ID's of latest git push? Or I actually overlooked something here, and there are some more trivial ways to do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, I just found this link:

[git: empty arguments in post-receive hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762084/git-empty-arguments-in-post-receive-hook)

which gave me a great hint, and here is how I solved the problem

In the `post-receive` of git:

```
read oldrev newrev refname
REV=$(git rev-list $oldrev..$newrev)
trac-admin <trac-repo>  changeset added <repo-name> $REV
```

p.s. that means the revision info are indeed passed into script via standard input, just the trac plugin could not get it for some reason.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know how to do this on Windows, wouldn't you?

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this gist that prevents duplication of commits when you use more than one branch:

https://gist.github.com/kenaniah/5471280