# git update hook not receiving any arguments

Tags: git, hook, githooks

I read up online that git hook accepts 3 arguments:

1. the name of the ref being updated,
2. the old object name stored in the ref,
3. and the new object name to be stored in the ref.

I am trying to access these arguments but it's empty. What could be wrong here?

```
#!/bin/bash


echo $@
refname="$1"
oldrev="$2"
newrev="$3"
```

Based on the comments, I tried adding an echo statement  `echo "In update hook: Args:$@"` and heres the output that I see:

```
$git push
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 563 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 0), reused 1 (delta 0)
remote: In update hook: Args:
remote:
remote:
```

Comment: Hooks need to be executable, did you make sure to `chmod +x $yourscriptfile` ? Also, make sure to remove the `.sample` naming from the hook file you are trying to excute.

Comment: Also, keep in mind some hooks don't receive arguments via the command line. See eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762084/git-empty-arguments-in-post-receive-hook

Comment: @BjoernRennhak The OP talks about update hook so `$yourscriptfile` is actually `.git/hooks/update`. :-) [Docs say](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#update) it really receive 3 parameters at the command line.

Comment: Have you put the script into `git/hooks/update` at the sever repo? Is it executable? Add an echo to verify it's really running, like `echo "In update hook. Args: $@"`

Comment: I did add an echo statement and see that the hook is being triggered but the arguments are empty

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Bjoern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2368241/bjoern-rennhak) for the reference link.
Based on the link you provided, I am able to retreive the arguments:

Source: [git: empty arguments in post-receive hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762084/git-empty-arguments-in-post-receive-hook) posted by [estani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1182464/estani)

```
read oldrev newrev refname
echo "Old revision: $oldrev"
echo "New revision: $newrev"
echo "Reference name: $refname"
```