# Get GitLab Runner build status in post-receive script?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, git-post-receive

### Context

After creating a general `post-receive` for a GitLab server, I noticed it gets triggered directly after a new commit is detected in any repository. However, I would like the `post-receive` script to do something with the build status of the GitLab Runner CI on the commit  that triggered the `post-receive` script.

### Approach

Based on [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13342417/7437143), I wrote a `post-receive` script that gets the commit and repository, and I tried to get the build status from that commit from within the GitLab docker:

```
#!/bin/bash
read oldrev newrev refname
echo "Previous Commit: $oldrev"
echo "New/latest Commit: $newrev"
echo "Repository name: $refname"

# Get build status of $newrev
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/17/$refname/commits/$newrev/statuses
```

However, that API call does not work from within the Docker environment (which is from where the `post-receive` script runs).

### Docker GitLab Build Status File locations

I also found the build status badges inside the Docker, they are located in: `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public/assets/`. However I do not (yet) know how to decode their filenames. For example, the build status badge accompanying `Job #3`, of commit: `9514d16aafc1d741ba6a9ff47718d632fa8d435b` has filename: `icons-6d7d4be41eac996c72b30eac2f28399ac8c6eda840a6fe8762fc1b84b30d5a2d.svg`. Basically I do not know to which commit/repository that build status badge belongs.

On the other hand, I have found the location of the job logs in the hashed path of the repository:

```
/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/d4/73/d4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35/2021_10_09/1/1/job.log
/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/d4/73/d4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35/2021_10_14/3/3/job.log
```

Which each in turn contain their respective commit and branch as:

```
Checking out 9514d16a as master...
```

So in principle I could scan the repository path and accompanying job logs until I found the `job.log` that contains the commit of the `post-receive` script (for e.g. 5 minutes, to account for the delay between the commit and the starting of the GitLab Runner CI), and then search for the build status output in that `job.log` (e.g. `Job succeeded`) (for e.g. 60 minutes to allow for long jobs). However, that seems like a convoluted work-around.

### Question

Hence, I was wondering, *Is there a better/faster/robuster method to get the GitLab Runner CI build status of the commit that triggered the general `post-receive` script of a GitLab server, inside that triggered instance/run of the `post-receive` script?

Comment: Git runs post-receive scripts immediately after receiving and accepting the commit. "Acceptance" is determined by: the pre-receive and update scripts (if present) allowed the commit, as did Git's own internal checks. There's no CI here, just a commit entering a repository. If the update script actually runs the CI to completion first, that would mean it's done when the post-receive script runs, but that would create other problems which would likely be insurmountable. So it seems likely that the CI code doesn't even *start* until around the same time the post-receive script runs.

Comment: In any case, how you can wait for a particular build, or even identify any particular CI run from within a post-receive script, will depend entirely on GitLab.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I initially was not completely clear on whether the `post-receive` was particular to GitLab or Git, its behaviour is defined by Git, and the CI's behaviour is defined by GitLab's runner. After processing your comments, I narrowed down the question to finding the build status of a particular commit from within the GitLab Docker.